# Why my UITableView loading quicker than view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, view

My **MainViewController**(1st Image) contain `UICollectionView` and when you click cells of `UIColectionView`, it pushes you to **SecondViewController**(2nd Image).

As you can see while it passing to **SecondViewController** -*just a few seconds*- you are still seeing some part of **MainViewController**. I think my UITableView in **SecondViewController** loading quicker than view itself.

What might be the reason of that? It has begun to disturbed me.

[image: MainViewController][image: SecondViewController]

Comment: I guess if you follow this, it will work well. That's because of default pushbehaviour : https://github.com/Kaibin/Common_iOS/blob/master/Core/Application/UINavigationController%2BRetro.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution of my problem. My **SecondViewController**'s background was set as *`default`*. Basically, I changed my background color as a white from `attributes inspector` and it's done!